# Getting Oracle 11.2 Unsupported Error when using Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.0.1

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-task

I am trying to set up SCDF 2.x (Spring Cloud Data Flow) server, to register Spring Boot applications (e.g. Tasks type) , to leverage out of box administration and other capabilities.

In setting up SCDF 2.x, was trying to connect to new `'dataflow'` schema on Oracle 11.2 (for job registry), but upon starting the `dataflow` server from command line (with Oracle JDBC in classpath), getting below error. Any suggestions will be helpful to resolve (as we are tied to Oracle as enterprise supported.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEnterpriseUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Enterprise Edition or Oracle upgrade required: Oracle 11.2 is past regular support by Oracle and no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Enterprise Edition. at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

our oracle version is **11.2**

Tried overriding the flyway dependency in project pom, but less than 5.x is giving `NoMethodFoundError`

Comment: Please someone can give any suggestion including spring developers, as this is major show stopper for our migration to Spring Cloud Dataflow

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

finally I've made an advance with this problem, in my case was enough with removing the flyway autoconfiguration and loading a bean called FluentConfiguration. I've made a project with the dependencies of spring cloud dataflow and then an SpringBootApplication class with this configuration:

```
import org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.EnableDataFlowServer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = FlywayAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableDataFlowServer
@Import(FluentConfiguration.class)
public class MyCompanySpringCloudDataflowApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyCompanySpringCloudDataflowApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

I know is not a neat solution, but is what I need to advance.

Of course, the database schema isn't automatically created, you must create it before running the application.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: nice. for those who needs the create sql, you may refer to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/f6289050956de5f51319120edca930689d68371e/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core/src/main/resources/schemas/oracle